# AS3 After button click unrelated functions are called

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

i am new here and i really need help.
Working on flash project and i encountered a problem. What im trying to do is let the user select the files with restricted file extensions like *.png, *jpg. After files are selected flash shows a little thumbnails of the pictures at the left cornern plus i push the filereferences to the new array so that when the upload button is clicked, files would get uploaded. Project files are [here](http://www.mediafire.com/download/x98pda90iauho1a/page.zip). The thumbnails arrangement is not as i wanted in the provided files but that not the problem.

The problem is when the files are selected function gofurther draws the thumbnails which is fine but once i click upload_btn bytesAr function is being called again and draws all selected images. you can look how it behaves before and after the button is clicked [here](http://postimg.org/gallery/36adboilg/).

The part that gives me this problem is this:

```
function uplFile(e:Event):void
        {
            for (var i:Number=0; i<fileUp.length; i++)
            {
                fileUp[i].upload(loaDur);// this line
            }
        }
```

If i comment the line inside loop which uploads the files, than everything is fine, but if i leave it it calles the bytesar function, draws the thumbnails from fileUp array all over again even though the parameters that i gave to that function is file:filereferenceList, plus there is no bytesarr function reference in the uplFile function so how is it being called? Can someone help? thanks

```
public class uplClass extends MovieClip
{
    var filter:Array = new Array(new FileFilter("Images (*.jpg, *.jpeg, *.gif, *.png)","*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.png"));
    var loaDur:URLRequest = new URLRequest(( stage.loaderInfo.parameters.f )? stage.loaderInfo.parameters.f : './upload.php');
    var file:FileReferenceList;
    var fileUp:Array = new Array();
    var numb:Number = 0;
    var track:Number = 0;
    var loadeR:Loader;
    var bitmap:Bitmap;

    public function uplClass()
    {
        file = new FileReferenceList();
        setup(file);
        select_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, browse);
        //cancel_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, cancel_func);
        upload_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, uplFile);
        cancel_btn.visible = false;
        upload_btn.visible = false;
    }
    public function browse(e:MouseEvent)
    {
        file.browse(filter);
    }
    private function setup(file:FileReferenceList)
    {
        file.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, select_func);
    }
    private function error_func( e:IOErrorEvent )
    {
        var tf = new TextFormat();
        tf.color = 0xff0000;
        label_txt.defaultTextFormat = tf;
        label_txt.text = 'The file could not be uploaded.';
        cancel_btn.visible = false;
        select_btn.visible = true;
    }
    private function select_func( e:Event )
    {
        for each (var fileRef:FileReference in file.fileList)
        {
            fileUp.push(fileRef);
            fileRef.load();
            fileRef.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, bytesAr);
        }
        function bytesAr(e:Event):void
        {
            loadeR = new Loader();
            loadeR.loadBytes(e.target.data);
            loadeR.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, gofurther);
            //track++;
            //count_txt.text=file.toString()+"1 "+fileUp.toString()+" "+numb;
            //trace(file+"1 "+fileUp);
        }
    }

     function gofurther(e:Event):void
    {
        bitmap = e.target.content;
        bitmap.scaleX = 0.2;
        var thumbLoad:Sprite = new Sprite  ;
        thumbLoad.graphics.beginBitmapFill(bitmap.bitmapData,null,false,true);
        thumbLoad.graphics.drawRect(0,0,30,30);
        thumbLoad.graphics.endFill();
        thumbLoad.x = 100 * numb;
        addChild(thumbLoad);
        numb++;
        //count_txt.appendText(numb+" ");
        if (upload_btn.visible == false)
        {
            upload_btn.visible = true;
        }
    }
    function uplFile(e:Event):void
    {
        for (var i:Number=0; i<fileUp.length; i++)
        {
            fileUp[i].upload(loaDur);// if i comment this line everything is fine, but if i leave it like this it calls bytesAr function somehow
        }
    }
}
```

}

PHP code to move uploaded files:

> $uploads_dir = './uploads/';
>
> if( $_FILES['Filedata']['error'] == 0 ){  if( move_uploaded_file(
>   $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'],
>   $uploads_dir.$_FILES['Filedata']['name'] ) ){         echo 'ok';      exit();
>     } } echo 'error'; exit();

Answer (score 0):

```
fileUp.push(fileRef);
fileRef.load();
fileRef.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, bytesAr); // <- see this? where are you removing it?
```

Now check the `upload()` of `FileReference`:
*complete:Event — Dispatched when the file upload operation completes successfully.*

You are actually firing the same listener after the upload completes. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey, @Fygo thanks for helping, im not sure if i follow but when i add eventlistener to fileref, once it completes and goes to bytesAr function i should remove the listener? like fileref.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, bytesAr) ? i tried that before posting this, i tried removing all the listeners after they call the function but that did not helped..